# Get memory high water mark for a time interval

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management

I'm trying to get the max amount of memory used during brief intervals, for a long-running linux process. For example, something like:

```
resetmaxrss(); // hypothetical new command
void* foo = malloc(4096);
free(foo);
getrusage(...); // 'ru_maxrss' reports 4096 plus whatever else is alive

resetmaxrss();
void* bar = malloc(2048);
free(bar);
getrusage(...); // 'ru_maxrss' reports 2048 + whatever, *not* 4096
```

Options I've found and ruled out:

- [`getrusage`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrusage.2.html)'s max RSS can't be reset.
- [`cgmemtime`](https://github.com/gsauthof/cgmemtime) seem to use `wait4` under the hood, so isn't viable to query a process while it's running.
- [`tstime`](https://github.com/gsauthof/tstime) reports for exiting processes, so is also not viable to query a process while it's running.

Other options, none of which are good:

- Polling. Prone to miss our brief allocations.
- Instrumenting our code. We don't have access to all of the memory allocators being used, so this wouldn't be very elegant or straightforward. I'd also rather use values reported by the OS for accuracy.

Is there a way to do this, short of proposing a patch to the Linux kernel?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that since Linux 4.0, the peak RSS *can* be reset:

```
/proc/[pid]/clear_refs (since Linux 2.6.22)

    This is a write-only file, writable only by owner of the
    process.

    The following values may be written to the file:

    [snip]

    5 (since Linux 4.0)
        Reset the peak resident set size ("high water mark") to
        the process's current resident set size value.
```

That HWM/peak RSS can be read out with `/proc/[pid]/status` -> `VmHWM` or `getrusage()`.

[Patch RFC](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/linux.kernel/w6fXXxZv1qg)